# Why does a switch have different MAC addresses?

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, switching, layer2

I am working with Cisco Nexus 3000 switch. I was under the assumption that a switch will always have a single MAC address but when I ran the following command, it displayed two different MAC addresses though only the first two bytes were different.

```
show interface ethernet 1/17 mac-address

Output:
MAC-Address              Burn-in-Mac-Address
ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:12        ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:78
```

Each interface on the switch has a different MAC. Can someone explain to me the importance of this? When does the common MAC address and interface specific addresses be used?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco assigns a large block, e.g. 1024, MAC addresses to a switch supervisor for use in STP because Cisco defaults to PVST+ and needs a MAC address for each VLAN. Each interface that may send ethernet traffic needs a unique MAC address. Logical interfaces, e.g. SVIs, will also get MAC addresses.

Answer (score -1):

If we are having 24 port switch  then each port is equipped with mac -address .

Mac -address is layer2 contruct . To forward packet from layer3 to layer1. Layer2 acts as mediator hence frame is forwarded from layer2 to layer1 and layer2 to layer3 on basis of mac-address table .

**Mac -address table maps**

`Mac-address to switch ports`

Switch(config)#show mac address-table
Mac Address Table

---

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports

---

1. 00ld.70ab.5d60    DYNAMIC     Fa0/2
2. 00le.f724.al60    DYNAMIC     Fa0/3